# Problem of Numpy returning error while appending arrays

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, append

> "ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly

This is the error I am getting when I am trying to append `values.PFB` the code. `x` is a dataset of size [16754,3] and `a` is an array of just one's with a size of [16754,1]. As far as I understand the axis matches exactly.

```
# Importing the libraries
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# Importing the dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv('data_monthly_rainfall.csv')
x = dataset.iloc[:, [0,1,2]].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, 3].values

# Appending a column y with 1 for the equation
import statsmodels.api as sm
a = np.ones((16754, 0)).astype(int)
x = np.append(arr = a,values = x, axis = 1)
```

Can anyone please tell me what am doing wrong here? I am very new to python and ML, in the learning phase. Please let me know if more info is needed.

[Link to the dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/redikod/historical-rainfall-data-in-bangladesh)

Comment: `np.append` with `axis=1` is just `np.concatenate([A, B], axis=1)`.  Use that instead.  And why are you trying to join an array with a size 0 dimension?  That's a useless step.  Use `x`.  If this is part of a loop, use list appends instead.

Comment: Check and double check the dimensions of `a` and `x`.  This works: `np.append(arr=np.ones((10,0)), values=np.ones((10,3)), axis=1)`

Comment: Thank you for the replies. But I tried both, its giving me the same error. That 0 is a mistake, I have edited it to one, it's still not working. Basically, my requirement is to add a column with 1 and append it at the starting of x.

Comment: What's `x.shape` and `x.dtype`?  We may also need to see the full error with traceback.

Comment: Thankyou @hpaulj the issue is resolved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the shape of `x` is (16755, 3) and you are creating `a` with a shape of (16754, 1). The mismatch occurs on the rows. Change the dimentions of `a`  to **(16755, 1)**:

```
a = np.ones((16755, 1)).astype(int)
```

You can avoid this altogether by saving the number of rows in a variable.

```
m = x.shape[0]
a = np.ones((m, 1)).astype(int)
x = np.append(arr = a,values = x, axis = 1)
```

Comment: While this is a pretty obvious problem with the code in the question, it wouldn't cause the claimed error, and fixing it wouldn't fix the claimed error. We don't have enough information to diagnose the cause of the claimed error.

Comment: @user2357112 is correct, I have tried that too. But it didn't fix the error. Can you tell me what more information is needed?

Comment: @SreedevR: We need something we can run, that produces the error you describe when run. We can't run what you've posted, since we don't have the original value of `x`.

Comment: I have added more info to the question. Dataset is also linked in the desc. I am trying to make a model which can predict rainfall. y is rainfall and all other values are x.